# unset post ajax php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am making a script like a shopping cart using js ajax and php.

this code lines are used to print remove when an item is saved:

```
if($_POST['button-statut']=='save'){        
    echo "remove";
    unset($_POST['button-statut']);
}

if($_POST['button-statut']=='remove'){
    echo "save";
    $_POST['button-statut']='save';
}
```

When i click in the save button, the value 'save' is set and if i click in the remove button it looks like the value is stil 'save' instead of 'remove'. what can i do ?

the save function:

```
$.post(host+"button.php", {"button": key, "button-statut":'save'});


    $('#button'+key+'').load(host +'button.php', {"button": key, "button-statut":'save'});
```

the remove function:

```
  $.post(host+"button.php", {"button": key, "button-statut":'remove'});

    $('#button'+key+'').load(host +'button.php', {"button": key, "button-statut":'remove'});
```

Thanks

Comment: What value do you want to unset?

Comment: can ask the question again with proper meaning ?

Comment: Based on your example, there is no need to unset `button-statut` as it would never match another if statement.

Comment: What is your problem? Have you tried that code? As for me, it looks Ok. `unset` should work fine there.

Answer (score 0):

These variables  are superglobal :

```
$GLOBALS
$_SERVER
$_GET
$_POST
$_FILES
$_COOKIE
$_SESSION
$_REQUEST
$_ENV
```

we cannot unset or clear theis input arrays. However, what we have done is to replace them with an objec (or empty its value)

Comment: When i click on the remove button, the script is reloaded, and the value in the post array is still 'save' so it prints "remove" and i wish it prints 'save', so if i'll have the possibility  to set 'remove' as the value it could prints 'save'.